# Count sibling elements that all have same unknown class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I need help working with a large list of sibling elements with different class names.

1. Getting the amount of elements with the same class name and putting them in an array
2. Finding first element in that class group (this can be number or name).
3. Statement that runs a function: if element = first element of group do `console.log("first element");`

Here's an example of the first 3 classes but this will go from groupA to Groupz

```
<div class = 'slider'>
    <div class = 'item1 groupA'> <!-- Start Group A -->
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>
    <div class = 'item1 groupA'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>                  
    <div class = 'item1 groupA'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>                  
    <div class = 'item1 groupA'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>
    <div class = 'item1 groupB'> <!-- Start Group B -->
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>
    <div class = 'item1 groupB'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>                  
    <div class = 'item1 groupB'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>                  
    <div class = 'item1 groupC'> <!-- Start Group C -->
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div>          
    <div class = 'item1 groupC'>
        <img  src='xyz'  />
    </div> <!-- All the way to group Z -->
</div>
```

Comment: The same class-name as the one that was clicked? Or arrays of all elements that share a given class-name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Your requirement is very specific. Below is just a sample to just loop thru all childrens and store the count and first element in the matching count. Let me

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.benton = function () {
        //just the immediate childrens
        var $chds = $(this).children();

        var lc = {
            firstEl: {},
            classCount: {}
        };

        $.each ($chds, function (idx, el) {
            if (el.className) {
               var tokens = el.className.split(' ');
               for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                   if (lc.classCount.hasOwnProperty(tokens[i])) {
                       lc.classCount[tokens[i]] += 1;
                   } else {
                       lc.classCount[tokens[i]] = 1;
                       lc.firstEl[tokens[i]] = $(el);
                   }
               }
            }
        });

        return lc;                   
    };

    var stats = $('.slider').benton();
    console.log(stats.classCount['groupA']);
    stats.firstEl['item1'].css({border: '1px solid red', width: 100, height: 10});
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LhwQ4/1/

---

I think what you need is to use context of slider to get the child elements.. see below,

```
var $slider = $('.slider')
```

Now using the $slider context,

```
$('.groupA', $slider)
//Returns Array of jQuery object with elements has class `groupA`

$('.groupA:first', $slider)
//Returns first element in collection of element with class `groupA`
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all elements with the same class name, you would only have to use a simple jQuery selector. The returned value is an array containing all matching elements.

```
var groupA = $(".groupA");
```

To get the number of items you need only access the length parameter of the array.

```
var groupALength = groupA.length;
```

If you want to extract only the first element of any matched elements, you can use jQuery's `:first` selector.

```
var firstElement = $(".groupA:first");
```

Comment: Thanks But what if there are 30 different class names and you don't want to write a variable for each one?

Comment: @im_benton one option may be to store all the names of the classes in an array, and then iterate through using a `for` loop. You could also use that array to build a selector that grabs elements with those classes (e.g. `$('.classOne, .classTwo, .classThree')`).

Comment: @im_benton How do we know what to look for? You mean something like parse and get those 3 criteria saved based on different class used?

Comment: @Vega i think so yes. I was hoping there was a way to store the class name and count all the elements the the same class.

Comment: @im_benton Try my demo http://stackoverflow.com/a/12465999/297641.. it is just a demo but should have all that you asked.. give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this solution is quite sensitive. I'm making a few assumptions about your HTML.

In your example you gave each item a class of `item1`.  I am assuming that this is just an issue of copying and pasting the element. Each "item" should have the same class so that you can retrieve all the items with one selector. For my example, I'm assuming a class of `item`.

There should be only this `item` class plus an additional "group" class.  Any other class given to the item will render this solution invalid.

```
// fetch ALL items
var allItems = $(".item");

// initialize groups array
var groups = {};

$.each(allItems,function(index,elem){
  var item = $(this);
  var itemClass = item.attr('class');

  // remove the "item" class and any leftover whitespace
  itemClass = $.trim(itemClass.replace('item','')); // should now be groupA/groupB...

  // add item to array at the index of the group
  if (groups[itemClass] == undefined){
    groups[itemClass] = [];
  }

  groups[itemClass].push(item);
});
```

You should now be left with an array of arrays containing all the items. To see this in action, you can check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHYxr/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = {};
$(".slider").children().each(function(i, el) {
    var classes = el.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++)
        if (classes[i] in groups)
            groups[classes[i]].push(el);
        else
            groups[classes[i]] = [el];
});
```

Now, you can access all elements of a group via `groups["groupA"]` etc (jQuery collection: `$(groups["groupB"])`) and the first one via `groups["groupC"][0]`. The amount of elements in a group is just the `length` of the array.

Notice that this puts all elements in the group `"item1"` - I don't know what you need that class for.